# Why is my neural network accuracy so low?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am new to machine learning and have been getting myself to learn neural networks. This week I've tried coding a neural network using this dataset. https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/abalone

The dataset contains details of individual abalones such as their size, gender, etc. My goal with this dataset is to predict the ages of abalone. This could be done by multiplying the rings of abalone by 1.5 as the dataset also reveals how one ring contributes to around 1.5 years of age. Therefore, my goal is to use a neural network to predict the number of rings an abalone has. That way, I will know its age as well.

I decided to have 4 layers with 300 nodes in the hidden layer and 1 in the output. Here is my code:

```
abalone_ds = pd.read_csv('abalone_ds.csv', header=None, prefix='V')
abalone_ds.columns = ['Sex', 'Length', 'Diameter', 'Height',
                   'Whole weight', 'Shucked weight',
                   'Viscera weight', 'Shell weight', 'Rings']


def one_hot(ds, column_name):
    return pd.get_dummies(ds, columns=[column_name])

abalone_ds = one_hot(abalone_ds, "Sex")

y_ds = abalone_ds["Rings"]
x_ds = abalone_ds.drop(columns="Rings")

x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = skl.train_test_split(x_ds, y_ds, test_size=0.2)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu', input_shape=(10,), name='Layer_2'))
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu', name='Layer_3'))
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu', name='Layer_4'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu', name='Output'))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=100, epochs=5, verbose=1)

test = model.evaluate(x_val, y_val, verbose=1)

print(test)
```

I first labeled the columns of the dataset as they were not labeled. Then, while I was analyzing the data, I realized that only "Sex" was non-numerical, so I encoded it to a one-hot tensor. Then, I split up the data (8:2 ratio) and plugged it into the network. The result was not promising.

[Here is the image to the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyI49.png)

You could see that my accuracy is 0 for the output layer. Moreover, the error is 1.57 rings which equivalents to 2.355 years. No matter how much I experiment/change the number of nodes or the number of layers, this accuracy value would not change.

I am not sure why this would happen. Perhaps, my understanding of what neural network outputs are wrong? For example, maybe the (1.57, 0.0) doesn't represent the number of rings and the accuracy level. Maybe this dataset is not qualified for the neural networks (meaning other algorithms are better suited). If anyone has any idea of why this is occurring or how I could improve my current code with explanations, I would gladly appreciate it.

Comment: Since it's not actually a coding problem, this quesition may be a better fit for the [datascience.se] stack site

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; I will definitely do it in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be the following: From your description of the problem you are trying to perform a *regression* task, i.e. predicting the age of the abalones. The age could in theory be any positive real number. Therefore, the accuracy metric you are using here is unsuited to the task, since it is used for *classification* tasks, that is, when the output belongs to one of a fixed and discrete set of possibilities. Therefore I would suggest using a different metric to measure your model results, such as Mean Squared Error or Mean Absolute Error, which are suitable for regression.

Also, note that while your metric (accuracy) has a value of 0, your loss function *is* decreasing with each epoch, which shows your model is improving :)

Comment: Ok, I understand your point. So I should use a regression model instead of classification. What if I represent the model as a classification knowing that the age has to be between 0 and 19. How would I change my code then?

Comment: You can convert it to categories 0, 1, . . ., 19 (must be integers) by one-hot encoding the response with `y_onehot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_ds, num_classes=20)`. Here `y_onehot` will be an array of shape `(num_examples, 20)`. Now your model's output must have the same shape, so you should change the last layer to `Dense(20, activation="softmax")` and your loss function to `categorical_crossentropy`.

Comment: I tried one_hot encoding y_ds by using the {y_onehot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_ds, num_classes=20)}, but I got this error: {index 22 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 22}

Comment: Hmmm. . . sounds like your ages go above 20. In this case you can either truncate all ages above 20 to 20 with `y_ds_trunc = np.minimum(y_ds, 20)` and then calling `to_categorical` on `y_ds_trunc`, or you could set the `num_classes` parameter to `max(y_ds) + 1` to ensure all classes are covered.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve the issue. It seems like there were up to 29 rings, so I changed the one_hot encoding parts and the nodes in the output layer. I was able to get 25% accuracy. Do you have recommendations to increase this accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

To frame this as a classification problem you would have to create 20 classes. Your training set now needs to assign a class (age) to each training sample. Your model than has to classify which class a sample is in. The last dense layer in your model would be

```
classification=Dense(20, activation= 'softmax')
model.compile(Adam, loss=sparse_categorial_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy']
```

Comment: I see. I've also seen many people use "categorical_crossentropy" as their loss function. What would be the difference between "sparse_categorial_crossentropy" and "categorical_crossentropy"? Moreover, how would my program know which classes to classify if classes aren't defined? For example, if I want the output to be in between the integer value 0 and 19 years, how does the program know to not produce decimal values?

Comment: I have also tried the above code. I got an error saying that "sparse_categorial_crossentropy" was not a known function. So I just went with "categorical_crossentropy" as the loss function, but I still get an error "Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 20) are incompatible"